# Liferay, reading from multiple language.properties file on same jsp

Tags: internationalization, liferay-6

I have a jsp file with the requirement of reading from the multiple language.properties file i.e with locales fr_CAN and other.Is it possible to read and display in same jsp file(Eg.based on the key in liferay-ui-message) by taking the value from these files with out changing the locale in sessions and with out using resource bundle.

For eg.
In **Language.fr_CAN.properties**

```
hello=Hello in canada french
```

and in In **Language.en_CAN.properties**

```
hello=Hello in canada english
```

Now in the Jsp file we have to display:

---

Say Hello...
Canada French   :   Hello in canada french

Canada English  :   Hello in canada English

---

Any help will be much appreciated..Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `<fmt:message/>` tag to achieve what you need.
For example you can try following in your Jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSTL fmt:message Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
    <fmt:requestEncoding value="UTF-8" />
    <fmt:setLocale value="fr_CAN"/>
    <fmt:setBundle basename="content.Language" />    

    <fmt:message key="say-hello" />
    <fmt:message key="greetings" />
    <fmt:message key="namaste" />
</body>
</html>
```

And in your **Language.properties** file:

```
say-hello=Hello in English
greetings=Greetings in English
namaste=Namaste in English
```

In **Language.fr_CAN.properties**

```
say-hello=Hello in canada french
greetings=Greetings in canada french
namaste=Namaste in canada french
```

and in **Language.en_CAN.properties**

```
hello=Hello in canada english
greetings=Greetings in canada english
namaste=Namaste in canada english
```

Here you can control the value to display in your jsp file by using `<fmt:setLocale />` tag.
Simply you can give it a value of the locale like "en_US", "fr_FR" or "en_CAN" to control the value it takes from the properties files.So set it in the request and display in the jsp as:

```
<% Locale locale = LocaleUtil.fromLanguageId(request.getParameter("locale-name"))%>
<fmt:setLocale value="<%=locale%>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call API instead of <liferay-ui:message /> tag:

```
<%= LanguageUtil.get(new Locale("fr", "CAN"), "your-message-key-here") %>

<%= LanguageUtil.get(new Locale("en", "CAN"), "your-message-key-here") %>
```